# How to break header titles in a table

Tags: tables

Please, how to break headers titles in a table ?

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}[h]{|p{2cm}||p{2cm}} 
\hline
{title one} & {title two}   \\ \hline\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{title}
\end{table}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `\parbox`es with line changing commands; inside the boxes you can use \centering to center the contents:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|} 
\hline
\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering title \\ one} & \parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering title \\ two} \\[3ex]
some text & some text \\
some text & some text \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{title}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used the vertical rules as visual reference points. On a side note, with such narrow columns, you could consider setting them ragged right.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works :) please, one more question how can center the titles in the cellule ?

Comment: @researcher You're welcome" For your new requirement, see my updated answer; I assumed you wanted to center only the title cells; if you wanted to center all the column, let me know.

Comment: Thank you so much for help :), yes how center all the column ?

Comment: @researcher load the array package: `usepackage{array}` and instead of `p{2cm}` use `>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}`

Comment: thank you so much Gonzalo :) my table is well, but i have a little problem, i have one title of coloumn is a bit long so it is written on the table row, i wish you understand me ..

Comment: @researcher either ask a fresh new question or edit your question add the actual code; otherwise, all we can do is guess and guessing is not a good way to go ;-)